# Show existence of unique inflection point using convexity and concavity definitions.

Tags: convex-analysis

Given $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x^3$, how could I show (using the definition of convexity and concavity of functions) that it has a unique inflection point?

Seeing as $f$ is continuous, I didn't use the general definition of convexity/concavity, but the Jensen one, i.e. (for convexity)

$$
f \left( \frac{x+y}{2} \right)  \leq \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}. 
$$

First I wrote out what the equivalent condition would be for $f(x)=x^3$. With some simple algebraic manipulations I get that the equivalent condition for convexity (the above formulation) would be that

$$
(x-y)^2(x+y) \geq 0,
$$

meaning $x+y\geq 0$, for all $x,y$ on the part of the domain on which $f$ is convex.

I could do the same for concavity and obtain the reverse inequality, however I'm not sure that helps me. Any hints?

EDIT: Since the condition for convexity is $x+y\geq 0$ for all $x,y$ on the part of the domain on which $f$ is convex, could I use the fact that then $x+x$ must be greater than $0$ (because obviously $x$ is in the same part of the domain as $x$), and with that I get $x\geq 0$.

Conversely, for concavity I get $x\leq 0$.

So the only point in which the function is both (or neither) is $x=0$?

Comment: @JimH no, but $3x^3-3x^2y-3xy^2+3y^3$ does, and that's what appears (after division by $3$)

Comment: comment withdrawn (I made a silly error)

Comment: It looks good to me.  Also, since we must have $x+y \ge 0$ for all choices of $x$ and $y$, They cannot have opposite signs, but must both be positive.  (I don't think it adds anything to what you've said, but it is clearer to me.)